# Electrical rough in

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting, rough-in

I have 2 question on electrical rough-in

1) For the outlet boxes, do I strip and wire nut the wires or just roll them up and tuck them in for the inspection?

2) For my recessed **canless** LED lights (see picture below). Can  I mount and wire the the j-boxes (driver boxes) for the rough in inspection?  If I don't wire them for the rough-in inspection, then once the sheet rock is up a) it will be difficult to mount, b) the inspector will have a hard time inspecting them.

[image: Canless LED light]

Comment: What do the instructions say about the LED lights?  You must follow the instructions and labeling, NEC 110.3b.

Comment: I would say those are questions to ask the inspector. I had some of my boxes stripped and connected, some not. All my can lights were wired, I just left the covers off. Inspector just told me to make sure I put them on before sheetrock goes up.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm in a similar boat